# Retina 4-inch iPhone 5 not desired top/bottom part

Tags: screen, coronasdk, retina

I am testing and implementation of SDK Corona as tested in xCode simulator are two areas at the top and bottom of the screen, which in the simulator iPhone5 crown are missing. I am using the "config.lua" recommended in many websites (code below) but I can not solve the problem.

I want my app to fit the entire screen.

http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2012/12/04/the-ultimate-config-lua-file/

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should have these images in your project file :

```
Default.png         - 320x480
Default@2x.png      - 640x960
Default-568h@2x.png - 640x1136
```

All images are just black images

Cheers ^^

Answer (score 2):

You can use the code given below -

```
  if system.getInfo("model") == "iPad" or system.getInfo("model") == "iPad Simulator" then

     application = {
           content = {
                    width = 360,
                     height = 480,
                    scale = "zoomEven",
                    audioPlayFrequency="44100",
                    fps = 30,

                    imageSuffix = {
                        ["@2x"] = 2,
                        ["@4x"] = 4,
                    }
            }
    }        
    -- For "tall" sizes (iPhone 5 and new iTouch)

  elseif display.pixelHeight > 960  then

    application = {
            content = {
                    width = 320,
                    height = 568, 
                    scale = "zoomEven",
                    audioPlayFrequency="44100",
                    fps = 30,

                    imageSuffix = {
                        ["@2x"] = 2,
                    }
            }
    }

    else -- For traditional sizes (iPhone 4S & below, old iTouch)

   application = {
            content = {
                    width = 320,
                    height = 480, 
                    scale = "zoomEven",
                    audioPlayFrequency="44100",
                    fps = 30,

                    imageSuffix = {
                        ["@2x"] = 2,
                    }
            }
    }
end
```

This code will be used in config.lua.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

This file is required.  The name must be an exact match.  If the extension is .PNG it won't work.